# count(distinct request_ip) GROUP by date

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have the following SQL, which I am using against AWS ELB logs stored in S3 with AWS Athena.

```
SELECT count(distinct request_ip) AS
 count,
 request_ip,
 DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp)) AS date
FROM "default"."aws_elb_logs"
WHERE request_ip = '10.0.2.1'
GROUP BY request_ip, DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp))
```

when i run the query, i get

```
request_ip  total   date
1   10.0.2.1    1   2020-12-24
2   10.0.2.1    1   2020-12-25
```

how do i count the total IPs and group these by date for a specific IP?

any advise is much appreciated

Comment: I'm just lost.  The first column should always be `1`.  What does it mean to count "total IPs . . . for a specific IP"?  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script.

```
SELECT count(request_ip) AS count,
       DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp)) AS date
FROM "default"."aws_elb_logs"
WHERE request_ip = '10.0.2.1'
GROUP BY DATE(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query by changing your timestamp and execute this

**Athena query:**

```
 SELECT distinct request_ip, count() as count from elb_logs
 WHERE parse_datetime(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z') 
 BETWEEN parse_datetime('2020-12-24-00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss')AND parse_datetime('2020-12-25-12:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss')GROUP by request_ip
 ORDER by count() DESC;
```

This will you give the total sum count of request_Ip  with the count of hits made to the lb

**Output eg:**

```
   request_ip     count    
1   10.0.2.1        5    
2   10.0.2.1        10
```